# Запрос по url проходит 2 раза , хотя должен 1 раз

Tags: swift, swift3

Результатом работы должно быть смс пользователю,которое почему-то приходит 2 раза, код на Java c Android app отправляет 1 смс, так что проблемы с сервером исключены

```
    let url2=URL(string:"здесь урл="+PhoneTextField.text!)
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let userPasswordString = "user:pass"
    let userPasswordData = userPasswordString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    let base64EncodedCredential = userPasswordData!
    let authString = "Basic \(base64EncodedCredential)"
    config.httpAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization" : authString]
    config.requestCachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
    config.urlCache = nil
    URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
    let session = URLSession.init(configuration: config)

        let task=session.dataTask(with: url2!){
            ( data, response, error) in
                let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
              self.dataStringJSon=dataString as String?
            if(self.dataStringJSon!=="User not found"){

            }else{
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil);
                    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MySecondSecreen") as! UIViewController;
                    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil);
                }

            }

        }

        task.resume()
```

Comment: запустите web proxy, посмотрите точно ли что то отправляется два раз. в коде проблем вроде нет. возможно весь этот блок кода выполняется дважды - поставте брейкпоинт на task.resume

Comment: После отключения basic auth на сервере,запросы дублироваться перестали